# postgres: list all column names that have unique index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to list all column names of a table and show whether or not it has a unique index applied to it. I can show all unique indexes per table/schema but not per column. This is the closes I have come to it:

```
select 
    ns.nspname as schema, 
    idx.indrelid :: REGCLASS as table_name, 
    idx.indisunique as indu, 
    i.relname from pg_index as idx 
  join pg_class as i on i.oid = idx.indexrelid 
  join pg_namespace as ns on i.relnamespace = ns.oid 
where NOT ns.nspname like 'pg%';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't own a PostgreSQL 11 DB for testing, so I am not quite sure if there is no error, but have a look at this (you can choose to omit the `WHERE`, but I guess system columns are not relevant to you, perhaps excluding `oid`):

```sql
SELECT
    n.nspname,
    c.relname,
    a.attname,
    (i.indisunique IS TRUE) AS part_of_unique_index
FROM pg_class c
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_index i 
        ON i.indrelid = c.oid 
            AND a.attnum = ANY (i.indkey[0:(i.indnkeyatts - 1)])
WHERE a.attnum > 0;
```

**NOTE**: `INCLUDE` is new for indexes in PostgreSQL 11. If you are on a lower version, use the following (you can also use this, if you also want to see the non-key-columns in PostgreSQL 11):

```sql
SELECT
    n.nspname,
    c.relname,
    a.attname,
    (i.indisunique IS TRUE) AS part_of_unique_index
FROM pg_class c
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_index i 
        ON i.indrelid = c.oid AND a.attnum = ANY (i.indkey)
WHERE a.attnum > 0;
```

**NOTE2**: This answer has been edited, saying `indnkeyatts` is the wrong field and you should use `indnatts` instead. I disagree with this, as this means that columns, which are only in the `INCLUDE` part of a unique index, would also be marked as having a unique constraint applied to them. But in fact, they are only stored in the index, but they do **NOT** need to be unique. So I think for the original poster, `indnkeyatts` is the way to go. If you want to see only included columns as well, use `indnatts`.

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to work, perhaps, a bit simpler.

```
SELECT c.table_name, c.column_name, t.*
    FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS t
        INNER JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS c
            ON t.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
            AND c.constraint_schema = t.table_schema
    WHERE t.constraint_type IN ('UNIQUE', 'PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY' ) 
         AND  t.table_schema = 'users' 
         AND t.table_name = 'users';
```

Comment: This solution only lists the indices that are part of a constraint. So while it might be useful it does not answer the original question.